# Cloud Computing Run an R script - easiest way to do it

Tags: windows, r, cloud, package

As I have an R script which takes months to run trough (in total) and I am out of time, I was looking for an Cloud Computing provider. I tested slicify but its based on Linux and to tricky (in this short time). Do you have A solution which is easy going?

What I have to do:

- Install R
- Upload my R script and .txt Dataset
- Install R packages (within the R script)
- Run the R script

The Results should be saved in the same folder as they will then be send via E-Mail.

What do you think will be the best solution for me?

Comment: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/EC2/CreateFromScratch.html

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/instructions-for-installing-using-r-on-amazon-ec2/